# Using JSP with Buttons

Tags: jsp, button

I have a button in a JSP page:

```
<button type="button" onclick="">Click me </button>
```

I want to perform the following jsp code:

```
<% session.setAtrribute("status","guest"); %>
```

when I press the button.

Is it possible to use JSP code on a button click and if yes how?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do something like this:-

```
    <% 
        if(request.getParameter("buttonName") != null) {
               session.setAttribute("status", "guest");
        }
    %>

    <FORM NAME="form1" METHOD="POST">
        <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="buttonName">
        <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Button 1" ONCLICK="button1()">
    </FORM>

    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
        <!--
        function button1()
        {
            document.form1.buttonName.value = "yes";
            form1.submit();
        } 
        // --> 
    </SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 4):

either use:

1. `<input type="submit" value="click"/>` and set form action to some servlet/jsp page where you set you'r session attribute
2. use ajax in onclick button method.

   JQUERY SAMPLE:

   ```
   $.ajax({
     url: "srvServlet", //or setJSP.jsp
     success: function(){
       alert ('ok');
     }
   });
   ```

Comment: I don't know ajax so, there is no another way other than form?

Comment: @Kristal  You just have to send data from client to server :). Either submit whole page or just par of it, but you have to submit something. If you don't line input:submit just use javascript function document.forms["myform"].submit();